# How to use POST parameters in Play Framework?

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to make a POST request using JavaScript routing. In the routes file:

```
POST /comments controllers.Clients.addComment(text: String, client: Int)
GET /assets/javascripts/routes controllers.Application.javascriptRoutes()
```

on page:

```
jsRoutes.controllers.Clients.addComment(args.text, @client.id).ajax(...);
```

But it creates the request

```
POST http://localhost:9000/comments?text=qwe&client=1 HTTP/1.1
```

How do I make it pass parameters in the POST body instead of a request string?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tak a look at [ajax() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) - that is, such example:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "some.php",
    data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
});
```

As [Play](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Play_Framework) JavaScript route already defines `url` and request method (`type`), you need only to add `data` (of course you don't need to specify them as a params in brackets)

```
jsRoutes.controllers.Clients.addComment().ajax(
    data: {
      client: @client.id,
      text: args.text
    }
);
```

Also you can send a text only to given client (determined by the URL (it can be `POST` but `PUT` looks nicer :)):

```
PUT /comments/:client     controllers.Clients.addComment(client: Int)
```

in the view:

```
jsRoutes.controllers.Clients.addComment(@client.id).ajax(
    data: { text: args.text }
);
```

So it will perform PUT request to `http://domain.tld/comments/123` and `text` will be available in the `form()` as it was sent with POST:

```
public static Result addComment(int client) {
    String receivedText = form().bindFromRequest().get("text");
    // save it to DB ...
    return ok( "Added comment: "+ receivedText+ ". for client id: " + client);
}
```

Comment: Works well. The {} are missing in the ajax function:
[...].ajax({
[...]
})

Comment: Excuse me, but why is PUT nicer? According to REST, a PUT should not change the state after request. Did you mean, a PUT with same comment should not add a new record, but just update the date of the appropriate comment (for example)?

Comment: And just for notice - link to how to define Play JavaScript route: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/JavaJavascriptRouter

Answer (score 0):

As i don't quite understand the JsRoutes in Play, what i did was:

In my view:

```
var client = 1;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/comments/" + client,
});
```

And in my routes, the call to the method:

```
GET /comments/:client     controllers.Clients.addComment(client: Int)
```

This works letting the browser make the request like a normal ajax call to some URL defined in routes.